# Basic token authorization in FastApi

Tags: http, http-headers, authorization, fastapi

I need help understanding how to process a user-supplied token in my FastApi app.

I have a simple app that takes a user-session key, this may be a jwt or not. I will then call a separate API to validate this token and proceed with the request or not.

Where should this key go in the request:

1. In the `Authorization` header as a basic token?
2. In a custom `user-session` header key/value?
3. In the request body with the rest of the required information?

I've been playing around with option 2 and have found several ways of doing it:

- Using `APIKey` as described [here](https://nilsdebruin.medium.com/fastapi-authentication-revisited-enabling-api-key-authentication-122dc5975680):

  `async def create(api_key: APIKey = Depends(validate)):`
- Declaring it in the function as described in the docs [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/header-params/)

  `async def create(user_session: str = Header(description="The Users session key")):` and having a separate `Depends` in the router config,

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to build a custom dependency using any one of the already existing authentication dependencies as a reference.

Example:

```py
class APIKeyHeader(APIKeyBase):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        name: str,
        scheme_name: Optional[str] = None,
        description: Optional[str] = None,
        auto_error: bool = True
    ):
        self.model: APIKey = APIKey(
            **{"in": APIKeyIn.header}, name=name, description=description
        )
        self.scheme_name = scheme_name or self.__class__.__name__
        self.auto_error = auto_error

    async def __call__(self, request: Request) -> Optional[str]:
        api_key: str = request.headers.get(self.model.name)
    # add your logic here, something like the one below
        if not api_key:
            if self.auto_error:
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail="Not authenticated"
                )
            else:
                return None
        return api_key
```

After that, just follow this from [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1) to use your dependency.